# Enabling triple-head setup with two Nvidia GT730 (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia, xrandr, multi-monitor

After installing a second Nvidia GeForce GT730 in the hope of overcoming a single card's limitation of only being able to support two monitors, I still cannot get a 3rd monitor working.

I keep the first two monitors connected to the firstly installed GT730 as they always have, and connect the 3rd one to the second card newly installed in the box.

arandr and `System Setttings` -->`Display` are equally not able to detect the 3rd monitor's existence, whereas the `nvidia-smi` output seems to suggest both cards are generally active:

Here's my driver situation

[image]

Well, I changed to 346.96 and rebooted after taking that screenshot, and it didn't solve anything.

```
$nvidia-smi
Wed Oct  7 16:40:16 2015       
+------------------------------------------------------+                       
| NVIDIA-SMI 346.96     Driver Version: 346.96         |                       
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GT 730      Off  | 0000:03:00.0     N/A |                  N/A |
| 42%   39C    P8    N/A /  N/A |      4MiB /  2047MiB |     N/A      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  GeForce GT 730      Off  | 0000:05:00.0     N/A |                  N/A |
| 42%   51C    P0    N/A /  N/A |    393MiB /  2047MiB |     N/A      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0              C   Not Supported                                         |
|    1              C   Not Supported                                         |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

But nothing I know of makes the second card jump into action with the 3rd display connected to it; arandr and the mentioned display settings screen do not detect the 3rd display, which is the only one connected to the second card.

Similar questions found here didn't seem to suggest a good path to a solution either because they were different OS or just different details. What should I check and how should I proceed?
Many thanks!

By the way, seems like the GT730 comes with no hardware that can connect an SLI bridge, or at least I can't possibly see such pins or connectors on the cards, SLI is likely not supported with this model.

Edit: The Nvidia configuration GUI is unable to persist the "advnaced" configuration of enabling Mosaic - it turns back to off even after clicking apply, saving to an empty /etc/X11/xorg.conf, and restarting the user session or rebooting.